# Making my program read 3 line individually

Tags: java, java-io, filereader

This is my program it reads from a file but I was away for the lecture for file readers so I'm winging it.
This program currently reads in one line and prints out the top 3 values from it but it only works with one line in the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ProcessdatdereFile
{
    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
        List namenum=readM("data/raw.txt");
        dataProcess(namenum);
    }

    public static List readM(String filename)throws IOException{
        Scanner fr=new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
        List<String>namenum=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(fr.hasNext()){
            namenum.add(fr.next());
        }
        fr.close();
        Collections.sort(namenum,Collections.reverseOrder());
        return namenum;
    }

    public static void dataProcess(List namenum)throws IOException{
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            System.out.printf("%s ",namenum.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

raw.txt contains

```
Mary 45 87 23 76
Joe 34 76 12 78 34 87
Anne 90 5 99
```

The program needs to print each name and the top 3 scores on individual lines.
Lengthy replies are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the question? What the problem?

Comment: change fr.next() to fr.nextLine()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException{
    String filename = "data/raw.txt";
    Scanner fr=new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));
    //reads the line and passes it to another method where it is put into a list
    String line;
    while(fr.hasNextLine()){
        line=fr.nextLine();
        List namenum=readM(line);
        dataProcess(namenum);
    }
    fr.close();        
}

public static List readM(String line)throws IOException{
    Scanner scn=new Scanner(line);
    List<String>namenum=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(scn.hasNext()){
        namenum.add(scn.next());
    }
    Collections.sort(namenum,Collections.reverseOrder());
    return namenum;
}
```

Ive changed these two methods so that it processes them as a line each rather than each string in the file. It now takes each Line and prints it out with the name and 3 top scores.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to sort here.

```
   Collections.sort(namenum,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

namenum is list of all individual item in file.

```
  Mary 45 87 23 76
```

Each item in this list is seperate  item in List.

You need to use nextLine(). For each line you need to skip the first token which is name and convert rest of the data on line in integer array and do reverse sort on that.

Comment: What that does is it produces Mary 87 76 45 23 and then I print the first 4 places
which is "Mary 87 76 45"

Comment: So its printing the three highest score. Wheres the problem?

Comment: the problem was it only printed one line from the file correctly,  if there was more lines it would mix all the results and it would say "Anne Joe Mary 99"